# Start-server-and-test "server closed unexpectedly"

Tags: node.js, azure, cypress

I'm using the [start-server-and-test package](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test) to start a server on my Azure pipeline to run Cypress.

This is the yarn command I use to start everything: `yarn cy:build:workspace`

> "cy:build:workspace": "yarn cy:clean && start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8080 cy:run:workspace"

I'm running NODE_VERSION: "12.10.0" on the Azure env.

```
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "d:\a\_temp\ce28689e-eef6-4eeb-bad2-82310f748e1b.cmd""
yarn run v1.22.4
$ yarn cy:clean && start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:run:workspace
$ rimraf cypress/reports/*
1: starting server using command "npm run start"
and when url "[ 'http://localhost:3000' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "npm run cy:run:workspace"


> @someProjectsbs/suite-packages@0.1.1 start D:\a\1\s
> lerna exec --scope=@someProjectsbs/suite -- yarn start --all-apps

lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info ci enabled
lerna notice filter including "@someProjectsbs/suite"
lerna info filter [ '@someProjectsbs/suite' ]
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "yarn start --all-apps"
$ cross-env react-app-rewired start --extended-linting --all-apps
[]
[info] [webpackbar] Compiling @someProjectsbs/suite
(node:4672) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.100/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\a\1\s\packages\app\suite\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

lerna success exec Executed command in 1 package: "yarn start --all-apps"
Error: server closed unexpectedly
    at ChildProcess.onClose (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\start-server-and-test\src\index.js:69:14)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\start-server-and-test\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Run Cypress testsk
```

Locally I have everything running, any suggestions why the server stops on the Azure environment?

Comment: Seeing exactly the same issue as of yesterday. Running in a docker executor on CircleCI. Also runs correctly locally. That would at least indicate it's not Azure specific.

Comment: https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test/issues/253

Comment: Maybe you can post that you're having the issue as well so there might be some more incentive for them to fix it.

Comment: I've spent the day debugging this and I'm becoming certain it relates to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688 A number of people there are reporting the issue on CircleCI. The proposed `sed` solution is one of the worst kludges I've ever seen, it simply deletes the problematic lines of code. The fact this kind of change/bug was released in a patch version is infuriating.

Answer (score 7):

Check your package.json, if you are using "react-scripts": "3.4.1" downgrade to 3.4.0

Also verify this link to use start-server-and-test with yarn, you need to add like strings some yarn commands https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test#note-for-yarn-users

Comment: Downgrading to 3.4.0 worked for me. Thanks for this.

Comment: Adding single quotes around my yarn commands did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but moving to `wait-on` solve the issue to me

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server

Comment: I gave this a +1 because it got me on the right track. I actually am using the npm package `wait-on`, but same idea

Answer (score 1):

Set the `CI` environment variable to `true`. Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688#issuecomment-642309787